# zero-padding a string in gcc with printf

Tags: c, printf

Here is my test program:
    #include

```
int main()
{
  const char *npa = "541";
  printf("%04.4s\n", npa);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[user@host:/work/user]# gcc -o test test.c
[user@host:/work/user]# ./test
[user@host:/work/user]#  541
```

In my understanding, it should be printed out `0541`, instead of `541`, right? How come gcc doesn't honor the padding flag?

Update:
Thanks for all comments provided. Problem is, I have some other strings that are not purely digits and still want them to be padded with leading zeros, any walk-around over this limit?

Comment: Zero-padding works over integers, use `printf("%04d\n", 541);`

Comment: You're confusing `%s` for string and `%d` for integers. `uint16_t npa = 541;
  printf("%04d\n", npa);`

Comment: To be directly clear, zero padding does not apply to strings. See the `printf` format specifier documentation for details.

Comment: You did notice the leading space printed in front of `541`, didn't you? Also GCC, for example, with more warnings enabled `-Wall` issues a warning on what the codes does.

Comment: Thank you, @alk. The `-Wall` option does help.